# Why is this code slow in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python.
I know a bit c++, worked with arrays. Arrays in c++ are not this slow.
Is it the list that slows it down? I'm not sure if it's possible to use tuples.

```
import random
list1=[]
n=1000000
for i in range(n):
    list1.append(random.randint(1,6))

x1=list1.count(1)
x2=list1.count(2)
x3=list1.count(3)
x4=list1.count(4)
x5=list1.count(5)
x6=list1.count(6)

xp1=(100*x1)/n
xp2=(100*x2)/n
xp3=(100*x3)/n
xp4=(100*x4)/n
xp5=(100*x5)/n
xp6=(100*x6)/n

print("The number 1 was found %d - %.2f percent" %(x1,xp1))
print("The number 2 was found %d - %.2f percent" %(x2,xp2))
print("The number 3 was found %d - %.2f percent" %(x3,xp3))
print("The number 4 was found %d - %.2f percent" %(x4,xp4))
print("The number 5 was found %d - %.2f percent" %(x5,xp5))
print("The number 6 was found %d - %.2f percent" %(x6,xp6))
```

Comment: python is interpreted and run on a virtual machine while c++ is compiled to machine code, so it will always be a lot slower than c++...

Comment: @AHL - Yes, it does need to be run a million times to generate a million random numbers. Running it only seven times would result in only seven random numbers, which isn't a very big sample (why seven, anyway?).

Comment: @Gusman This point has been made on this website very often but was proven very rarely.

Comment: @KlausD. there's no need to prove it, it's just a matter of logic, C++ will be compiled to very little assembler instructions while a virtual machine will execute a lot more of asm code, so it will be slower. If you want some realistic comparisons just look at this: http://flux242.blogspot.com.es/2013/09/javascript-vs-perl-vs-python-vs-lua.html you can see its a lot slower.

Comment: @Gusman I basically see very different code for the different languages, so the link features a rather bad comparison. And BTW the one who make a statement has the burden or prove. Your logic makes the assumption that the virtual machine is *much* slower than compiled code, which is actually the point to prove.

Comment: @KlausD. ok, whatever, if you want to stay blind to the reality is your problem, a virtual machine must execute at least twice asm instructions than a direct program as it must read the bytecode, interpret it and finally execute the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `random.randint(1, 6)` a million times is slow, it has little to do with your list:

```
In [18]: %timeit for i in xrange(1000000): random.randint(1, 6)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.33 s per loop
```

You can get even faster if you ditch `random.randint()` and switch to just `1 + int(random.random() * 6)` and use a list comprehension:

```
In [111]: %timeit for i in xrange(1000000): 1 + int(random.random() * 7)
1 loops, best of 3: 300 ms per loop
```

The easiest speed improvement would be to use `numpy`:

```
In [20]: %timeit numpy.random.randint(1, 7, size=1000000)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the list that dominates the running time, but  the call to `random.randint`. If you replace `list1.append(random.randint(1,6))` with `list1.append(1)` it'd be easily 10 times faster.

Also, a list comprehension should be slightly faster than `for` loop with `append`, thus you can try

```
n = 1000000
list1 = [random.randint(1,6) for i in range(n)]
```